# How to retrieve longText and SORT by TIME to echo them accordingly

Tags: php, mysql

In mySQL, i have a table of comment consist of userID,restaurantID and comments columns:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
 `loginID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `RID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `comments` longtext NOT NULL,
 KEY `loginID` (`loginID`)
 KET 'RID' ('RID')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

here's what I wanna do:

**i)** i would like to store comment + current time for the comments column.

I'll say (comments = comments + newinput + currentime + ",") in java. 
then convert $comment = $_POST['comments'] in PHP

**ii)** when I insert, i'm doing (Insert into comment (loginID,RID,comments) VALUES ('$loginID','$RID','$comment'));

so now the comments column consists of a long list of data like

(delicious 12:00:00, getting worst 23:00:00, ...) and so forth.

**iii)** i would like to show all of them row by row similar with google market comments which listed the userID and comments and the bottom.

my **question** is :

1) how should i get the data separately according to the comma? implode or explode? but i'm confuse with that..

2) when I (SELECT comments FROM comment WHERE RID = $RID);
I'll get a lot of userID & their comments list. How should i separate them all into pieces so that i can SORT them according to the Time posted and print the userID and comment from earliest time to current time.

Logic: (1 Restaurant can comment by many user, 1 user can leave many comments about the restaurant.)

Is it appropriate for me to store the data like this? (updating the text = text + currenttime + ",")

Answer (score 2):

As far as database structure and normalization goes, you're not off to a good start, and that's your problem right there.

You should be entering separate comments as separate entries into the comment table, with an additional column for the time. This way, you can easily sort by time using:

SELECT comments, time FROM comment WHERE RID = $RID SORT BY time ASC

This will get comments for a particular restaurant in chronological order (use DESC instead to get the most recent comments first).

This way you eliminate any unnecessary string manipulation - which always leads to bugs and a massive headache. It also allows you to use MySQL's built in date/time formats, allowing you to only select comments from the past week etc.

Comment: thank you for your guidance! but if i do so, would'nt the table be very large after some time?

Comment: It could get pretty big, depending on how many comments you expect there to be over the entire system. However, MySQL can handle very large tables efficiently, so I doubt you'll run into problems there.